# Access to Request's header in services.AddScoped in WebApi Core ConfigureServices?

Tags: request, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, request-headers

I want to assign a value to a class instance from Request's header to each request as singleton.
I wanted to assign it with .net core in `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup` class.
Something like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddScoped<MyClass>(provider =>
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.PropName = provider.Request.Headers["PropName"]; // I want to access Request Header here
    });
}
```

How can I access Request's header in `AddScoped` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **cleanest approach** is to change your `MyClass` Constructor as follows:

```cs
public MyClass(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    this.PropName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["PropName"]
}
```

Then in your DI setup:

```cs
services.AddScoped<MyClass>();
```

**Alternatively**, if you really need to access this in your DI setup, you can amend as follows:

```cs
services.AddScoped<MyClass>(provider =>
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.PropName = provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["PropName"];
});
```

Comment: Remember to add ```services.AddHttpContextAccessor()``` before ```services.AddScoped```